# How fix broken Macports installation after manual deletion of app?

Tags: macports

I had GIMP installed via `sudo port install gimp`. This created the `GIMP.app` in `/Applications/MacPorts/`. I accidentally deleted it manually (or with AppCleaner, not sure), so every time Macports scans installed binaries, it warns

```
Warning: Error parsing file /Applications/MacPorts/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP: Error opening or reading file
```

This is also what happens when I try to install again. I uninstalled and cleaned the port, but installing again does not work; the `.app` is not created and the above warning shows. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, but after I purged the unused dependencies of `gimp`, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts has a force option that allows you to continue, even in the case of errors.

I'd force-remove and then install it again.

Comment: To force what? Without `-f` the install completes, it is just that nothing happens.

Comment: I meant, force uninstall

Comment: I tried, to no avail.

Comment: So force removing and then installing it doesn't do anything? Whats in the macports log?

Comment: I ran `port -f uninstall gimp` and `port install gimp` again, and no change. The log says `...--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
Warning: Error parsing file /Applications/MacPorts/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP: Error opening or reading file
--->  No broken files found.`, so just the usual, except the warning. The `GIMP.app` is not created. There is a binary in `/opt/local/bin/gimp`, but running it does nothing. Previously, MacPorts also created the `.app` and judging from the warning it still tries to.

Comment: To clarify: you ran both commands as root?

Comment: Yes of course. Otherwise nothing would work.

Comment: Let me check on my installation and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Installing gimp on a clean system works fine here, so it's in your MacPorts. Let's try some things: sudo port clean all; sudo port selfupdate; sudo port upgrade outdated; sudo port uninstall gimp; sudo port install gimp

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this post, while looking for a similar issue with inscape. The following happened:

- I Installed inkscape on a MacOS 10.14 macbook via macports 2.5.4 (which was a quite painful experience...)
- At some point I did a system update after which inkscape seized to work - some issue with "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/poppler/lib/libpoppler.74.dylib"
- Hence I removed the Inkscape binaries manually from /usr/local/bin
- When trying to run

  $ sudo port install inkscape

I received an error message the inkscape files are unavailable at /usr/local/bin and didn't find any means to fix this issue.

Thanks to this post here I was able to resolve the issue by typing

```
$ sudo port -f uninstall inkscape
```

which enabled me to install inscape once again.